# Quicklook not working

Tags: finder, quicklook

Usually after I open quicklook and then close it again I cannot open quicklook again. And if I right click on an icon it lists exit quick look as an option but when I click it nothing changes.

What's my problem here?

I am on OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Try triggering QuickLook with space bar press?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open the Terminal application (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)
2. Type `qlmanage -r` and hit enter
3. Type `qlmanage -r cache` and hit enter
4. Type `killall Finder` and hit enter

This should force QuickLook to reload the generator lists and reset the disk cache.

Source: https://www.macissues.com/2014/03/22/fix-quicklook-errors-in-os-x/

Comment: That seems to have worked for now, however usually after a fresh restart it does work for a short period.  I will come back if I have problems again, but for now you win

Comment: This is back to not working again.  I don't feel like I should have to do this once a week

Comment: It could perhaps also be a plugin from a 3rd party that is breaking something. For example when you install Adobe Illustrator, it adds the ability to view .ai files in quick look. Have you noticed if it happens with a certain file type at first or have you installed any specific software that could cause this?

You can use `qlmanage -h` to give you some tools for debugging quick look, if you feel comfortable using this.

Comment: The solutions in Morten's answer both worked for a minute, but a minute later quicklook is right back to being broken again. Won't play audio files (video files work fine tho'...?!) Anybody got a permanent fix?

Comment: Instead of wasting your time on rebooting try terminal with `killall Finder` command first

Comment: Or Alt-Right-Click on the Finder icon and select Relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the function key and the spacebar fixed it for me.